# Detect processes that are accessing a certain device

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi

What I need to be able to do is detect the applications that are accessing a microphone/webcam device and on the user's command 'deny' access to the microphone/webcam device in use.

I've done a lot of research on the theme, and come to the following key questions:

1. It is possible to search for handles with a utility such as SysInternal's `handle.exe` but because of license issues and such I would much prefer to be able to do this in pure C# or a free utility.
2. To search for a device's handle  you need to know it's Physical Object Name, and apparently I haven't found any way to get this info via WMI.
3. How would I automatically determine what is the active microphone/webcam device? 
   Or am I required to query the user to find out?

If you can find an answer to any of these issues, I will be more than happy to read your thoughts.

Thank you all for reading and taking the time to process this post! Regards.

Comment: Do you know Process Hacker ? It has a similar function like handle.exe and the sourcecode is available. http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/. The sourcecode is in C I think, but the relevant API calls should be translatable to C#

Comment: Thanks @Marged. I'm really happy you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately after Microsoft bought SysInternals they decided no longer to provide the source code of the tools for download. [Older versions](http://web.archive.org/web/20060829135539/http://www.sysinternals.com/SourceCode.html) of some are still available, but handle.exe is not among them.

But as the C [source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/processhacker/code/HEAD/tree/) of [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) is available and that tools offer similar functionality, you might find what you are searching for in the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've noted Process Hacker already but I'm still unsure of whether it is the best solution (maybe there is a usable API after all?)